My obj file not showing red colours when imported
New to Blender. I have an obj file that clearly shows as red on Mac OSX. This is the only file I have. It looks like the following when I preview it in my Mac.

However, when I import it into Blender, it's all grey under the "Layout" tab. I don't understand what happened.
(https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4d3zuufhxcis1ifm5x8gj/B.obj?rlkey=i5fc7u1pcu38j7vh4sdq1tbes&dl=0)

Usually materials don't transfer 1:1 between different softwares. You have to set up the material in Blender.

As @Jakemoyo says, materials don't transfer and in fact there are no materials at all on the object after importing it into Blender. It also has terrible topology!

You only have an OBJ file. When you open this OBJ file with a text editor (i.e. Notepad), you will notice that it only defines vertices and faces but does not include any material definitions. To have at least some basic material properties on the model, the OBJ file needs to be accompanied by an MTL file which is also defined in the OBJ file. However, only simple materials are supported in this format. Other than that, please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
